# using SharpDX.Direct2D1 to render on specific element

Tags: wpf, direct2d, sharpdx

I'm working on rendering a buffer using SharpDX in a WPF application. I've created a `WindowRenderTarget` and I'm drawing a SharpDX Bitmap to it. Everything is working fine, but I'm facing an issue: the buffer is being rendered on the entire window, whereas I need it to be rendered onto a specific element within the window. How can I achieve rendering to a specific element using SharpDX in WPF?

Here's the code I'm using to rendering:

```
 private void InitializeDirect2D()
        {
            var hwnd = ((HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(image)).Handle;
            var factory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory1(FactoryType.MultiThreaded);
            var renderProps = new HwndRenderTargetProperties
            {
                Hwnd = hwnd,
                PixelSize = new Size2((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight),
                PresentOptions = PresentOptions.Immediately
            };

            var renderTargetProperties = new RenderTargetProperties
            {
                DpiX = 96,
                DpiY = 96,
                MinLevel = FeatureLevel.Level_DEFAULT,
                Type = RenderTargetType.Hardware,
                Usage = RenderTargetUsage.None
            };
            properties = new BitmapProperties(new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, SharpDX.Direct2D1.AlphaMode.Premultiplied));
            renderTarget = new WindowRenderTarget(factory, renderTargetProperties, renderProps);

        }
        public void DrawBitmap()
        {
            int width = frame.width;
            int height = frame.height;
            int stride = width * 4;
            IntPtr buffer = (IntPtr)frame.data[0];
            using (var stream = new DataStream(buffer, stride * height, true, false))
            {
                var bitmap = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap(renderTarget, new Size2(width, height), stream, stride, properties);
                renderTarget.BeginDraw();
                RawColor4 clearColor = new RawColor4(255, 255, 255, 255);
                renderTarget.Clear(clearColor);
                renderTarget.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 1.0f, SharpDX.Direct2D1.BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);
                renderTarget.EndDraw();
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

The above code works, but it renders the buffer across the entire window. Is there a way to target a specific element (e.g., a `Canvas` or an `Image` control) within the window so that the rendering is confined to that element only?

Thank you!
``

Comment: Once you've create an HWND render target (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget) on an HWND, the whole HWND surface is yours. You could use D3DImage instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.d3dimage but that requires architecture changes. WPF is (still) based on DirectX9 and doesn't play well with more modern technologies. One solution is to migrate to WinUI3 and use a SwapChainPanel instead (this is an element *inside the window, not the *whole* window). Depends on your context obviously, can be a big task.

Comment: I know that in WinForm, every control has its separate HWNDs, which means each control is actually a separate window under the hood. I don't know if WPF behavior is the same, but if it is, that would be very convenient. I mean, if you can somehow get the HWND of the element (control), you can just render to *that* HWND, and your purpose is achieved.